# Как при include указать относительный путь?

Tags: php

Допустим есть 2 файла. Файл foo.php инклудит файл bar.php

**Есть потребность указать относительный путь от файла bar**, например `realpath(..)`

Но так как bar.php включен в foo.php, это выведет путь относительно файла foo.php.

Есть ли возможность указать относительный путь для файла bar.php?

Временно разбираю `__DIR__` по `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` и добавляю нужные элементы, а потом снова преобразую в строку. Должен быть более простой путь.

p.s. [вот примитивный вариант временного решения](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0154fe2f31dd90a3b84fd9cf53370dacc40f1a23) (в реальной ситуации добавил ещё проверку на file_exists перед return)

Comment: Берёте и указываете относительный путь а-ля `../../dir/bar.php.`

Comment: Я бы написал функцию в bar.php для вывода __DIR__ . Или функцию для include в bar.php .

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы вопрос читали

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено: `realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')`

Не знаю почему сразу об этом не подумал...